# Tablet or 2-in-1 for programming and note taking

Tags: tablet

Looking for a tablet or 2-in-1 for heavy programming and note taking, preferably a tablet or a 2-in-1 with a detachable screen.

I care about how the writing feels so looking for a stylus/screen combo with a little bit of resistance if possible.

Aiming for high build quality and powerful components because I want it to last as long as possible.

Budget: 3500 USD

Size: preferably 12 inches

RAM: 16GB

Video card: not relevant

Battery life: not a priority

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Surface Pro (5th Generation) is a very good laptop (tablet) with a detachable screen and keyboard as specified.

As far as specs go, they cover your requirements with a model which has:

- Intel Core i7.
- 512 GB / 1 TB SSD.
- 16 GB RAM.
- 12.3" Display.

There is a stylus available for the Surface Pro and as far as build quality goes, the Surface Pro is exceptional, as would be expected from a high-end Microsoft product.

You can find more details here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/surface-pro/8NKT9WTTRBJK/L6FV?source=lp&activetab=pivot:techspecstab

The price of the 512 GB model is $2200 (currently $1799 as of this post).

This is probably one of the best choices out there for programming / note-taking.

Comment: I'm concerned about the review of the stylus.

Comment: @rosseg You won't find many other (let alone better) options.

Comment: Do you know if older surface pens are usable?

Comment: I'd assume they would be but I'm unsure as to whether or not there are any software features that would not be supported. Styluses in general have pretty bad reviews but I feel that's mainly because they are widely considered as overpriced - either way this is definitely one of the best ones out there.