# Need a 2in1 for coding, running scripts (to test my code), and note-taking/organizing my notes

Tags: laptop, gaming, tablet

I'm trying to find a solution to my current predicament with too many notebooks, stuck at my computer because I don't have any portability, and losing my notes because I have no organization regarding the notebooks.

I was hoping there would be a panacea to my ADHD. My reasoning for a 2in1 was that I could do everything that I wanted on one device, meaning I wouldn't have to get up out of bed to change one line of code that I observed was slowing performance down, or having to bend over backwards to grab one of my notebook, and just being able to monitor how my code is running on a portable device, though I'm not exactly sure if people generally get a 2in1 for coding and also running said code since I've only owned an iPad which didn't have much freedom to play around with stuff like that.

I think I'm just looking for an iPad kinda thing that I can code on, play Maplestory, and run my code alongside to test the code, since it's the reason I got into coding recently. I want to practice on something I'm familiar with and enjoy, and I hope that a 2in1 will be the catalyst that helps me work a little bit faster.

My goal is quality of life, not malicious intent, so I hope no one takes this the wrong way.

only relevant post i found was: [Tablet or 2-in-1 for programming and note taking](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9915/tablet-or-2-in-1-for-programming-and-note-taking?rq=1)
which is 4 years old, so i'm not sure if there are better options available now.

Answer (score 1):

Similar recent question: [A "pad" for note-taking, primarily](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17858/a-pad-for-note-taking-primarily/17904#17904)

The 2 in 1 market is pretty slim pickins right now where you need to pick from HP 2in1, Microsoft Surface, or Apple iPad.

Using a stand alone writing tablet will get you much better performance for the money, but it's not quite as convenient.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think it's best if I ignore the Apple iPad because I would like to be able to treat it like a portable PC that can run games when I'm testing development with coding. I know how restrictive iOS can be, and I don't think I'm planning to do any art or mobile gaming.

Standalone writing tablet probably wouldn't suit my need to run programs and stuff, right?  I'm probably going to find my answer with either a Surface Pro or something offered by HP or any other brand?